# How to use Elementree XML parsing from string in server side?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, sockets, elementtree

I've been trying to send an xml string through sockets from a client to a server. The idea is to parse this xml with ElementTree and then use the obtained element.

I can successfully pass the string from client to server, but regardless of how i build the xml in the client ( via file, triple quotes string or using the method within the ElementTree packages), in the server i keep getting the error

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0

I have validated the file/string and I'm not sure where's the mistake since i really don't have any experience in directly using XML files.

This is the XML string

```
RemoteFunction = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>somemethodname</methodName>
    <params>
      <param>
         <value><string>somevalue</string></value>
      </param>
      <param>
         <value><i4>1</i4></value>
      </param>
      <param>
         <value><string>anothervalue</string></value>
      </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>'''
```

And this is the connection handler function in server

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def client_handler( connection, address):
    connected = True
    while connected:
        msgLen = connection.recv(64).decode("utf-8")
        if msgLen:
            msgLen = int(msgLen)
            msg = connection.recv(msgLen).decode("utf-8")
            if msg == "!Disconnect":
                connected = False
            
            tree = ET.fromstring(msg)
```

Note: I am aware there's a library for XMLRPC in Python3 but I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: What do you get when you print `msg` before trying to parse it as XML?

Comment: This is the printed `msg` `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>somemethodname</methodName>
    <params>
      <param>
         <value><string>somevalue</string></value>
      </param>
      <param>
         <value><i4>1</i4></value>
      </param>
      <param>
         <value><string>anothervalue</string></value>
      </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>`

Comment: Your `msg` is valid xml which can be read fine by both ET and lxml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
def client_handler( connection, address):
    connected = True
    while connected:
        msgLen = connection.recv(64).decode("utf-8")
        if msgLen:
            msgLen = int(msgLen)
            msg = connection.recv(msgLen).decode("utf-8")
            if msg == "!Disconnect":
                connected = False

            doc = SimplifiedDoc(msg)
            print (doc.methodName.text, doc.selects('param>text()'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer as much as a mistake because i did not notice it was actually working from the start.

The problem was the client was sending 2 message

```
send(xmldata)
send(DisconnectMsg)
```

Even if it ElementTree parsed correctly the first message an error would pop out for the second message.